# Why can't i compare java.util.Date to mysql dates?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, jpa

i have a strange situation:

I'm using jpa/hibernate to get rows from a mySql DB table where a date column is greater or equal to a date i send in (stripped out irrelevant code):

```
SELECT sp.* FROM spaceproduct sp where sp.enddate is null or sp.enddate >= :endDate)
```

in my code i basically do:

```
q.setParameter("endDate", new java.util.Date());
```

Now, my problem is when the date in the DB is the same date. i.e. "today", it doesn't get picked up. I assume that it's because it somehow also compares the time portion of the java.util.date to what's in the database (db value is "2011-10-28' only but the java.util Date is 2011-10-28T13:36:43.130+0200)

However, if i change the date parameter i set into a java.sql.Date(), it works!

Now, given that my mySql DB column is a Date, and not a DateTime, isnt this a bug? Even if i send in a java.util.date, shouldn't it only compare the date part since my DB column is a date?

EDIT: i tried using a util-date and convert it into a sql-date. That actually doesn't work either:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
q.setParameter("endDate", sqlDate);
```

So from what i can see, i *have* to set the time part to 0 also for sql-dates, unless i use the deprecated "year-month-date" constructor...

Comment: No, it's not a bug. 2011-10-28 is not >= 2011-10-28T13:36:43.130+0200. Your date object has 2011-10-28T13:36:43.130+0200, therefore it fails. java.sql.Date however only stores day/month/year, or rather it only returns that when you call toString(), so it equals 2011-10-28.

Comment: Hey, thanks for input. See my edit comment above and say what you think mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` rather than creating a util `Date` to get that long. I would expect your edited code to work however, but if it doesn't you have no option but to discard the hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds in some way such as doing `System.currentTimeMillis() % 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` (of course better to store that in a constant, but it gets the point across). Or you could just use Joda.

Answer (score 1):

You should use java.sql.Date, as that is purely a date and does not contain time information.
The reason it works with java.util.Date is that either the database or the JDBC driver does a widening conversion of the column from DATE to TIMESTAMP (with 00:00:00 time part) to make the comparison work with the parameter.

Comment: btw. java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date

Comment: Mark, thanks for your thoughts. However, my main beef with sql-dates is that any "date-wide" constructor, i.e. year-month-date, are deprecated. You should basically use the long-constructor, and then i might as well use a JodaTime "datemidnight" instead... Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Ok, then I guess it is a bug in the Connector/J driver, as I just noticed it is actually the responsibility of the JDBC driver to convert java.sql.Date to the equivalent of a DATE (so without time portion). You could try to use a java.sql.Date.toString() and setString as a workaround.